# Pop-up confirmation not working in webview_flutter for iOS

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-dependencies

I am facing an issue with the webview_flutter package in my Flutter app. On Android, everything works fine. When I upload an item and try to delete it, a pop-up window appears asking for confirmation before proceeding with the deletion. However, on iOS, the pop-up window does not appear when I click on the delete button.

I have searched extensively for a solution but haven't found any relevant information or examples. I have already implemented the webview_flutter package correctly, and other functionalities are working as expected on both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement an extension to **FWFUIDelegate**, add this implement to **AppDelegate** file, and remember to import the module **webview_flutter_wkwebview**.

This implement will help you open **alertPanel** and **confirmPanel** for iOS **webview_flutter**.

Here is the implementation:

```
import webview_flutter_wkwebview

@objc //This annotation allow Swift can be reachable by Objective-C
extension FWFUIDelegate {
    @objc
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in
            completionHandler()
        })
        topViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @objc
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in
            completionHandler(true)
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
            completionHandler(false)
        })
        topViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(getCurrentWindow().rootViewController)
    }
    
    func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewController = viewController else { return nil }
        if let presentedViewController = viewController.presentedViewController {
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController)
        } else if let tabBarController = viewController as? UITabBarController {
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController)
        } else if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navigationController.visibleViewController)
        } else {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentWindow() -> UIWindow {
        var window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        if window?.windowLevel != .normal {
            for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
                if window.windowLevel == .normal {
                    return window
                }
            }
        }
        return window!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Flutter when trying to display a confirmation dialog box. I found this comment in the Github issue that was closed 3 weeks ago without an official solution:

[https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30358#issuecomment-574556188[1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30358#issuecomment-574556188)

```
onPageFinished: (url) async {
  try {
    var javascript = '''
      window.alert = function (e){
        Alert.postMessage(e);
      }
    ''';
    await _webViewController?.evaluateJavascript(javascript);
  } catch (_) {}
  setState(() {
     isLoading = false;
   });
},
```

In this block `onPageFinished` is a callback that gets executed when the WebView finishes loading a page. Inside this callback, a multi-line JavaScript string is defined that overrides the default window.alert function. Instead of showing a browser alert, the overridden alert function uses `Alert.postMessage(e)` to send the alert's message to the Flutter side of the app.

```
JavascriptChannel(
  name: 'Alert',
  onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
    // TODO popup
  },
 )
```

The second block defines a JavascriptChannel named 'Alert'. This channel listens for messages (like those sent from the overridden alert function). When a message is received via `Alert.postMessage(e)`, the `onMessageReceived` callback inside the JavascriptChannel is triggered. Inside this callback, you can then handle the message (which in this case is the alert's content) appropriately, such as showing a Flutter dialog or a toast message to display the alert to the user.

For my case, however, I needed to display a confirmation dialog, which is more complicated than the above code allows. As a workaround to the confirmation dialog, I created a hidden div with `display="none"`. Instead of showing the confirmation dialog, I update the div to `display="block"`, and inside the div are the message to display, the OK button, and the Cancel button. Here's the relevant code from my project:

```
<form id="confirmationForm" action="/schedule/?action=confirm_shift" method="post">
    <input class="confirm-btn" type="button" value="Confirm Shift" onclick="showConfirmation()">
    <input type="hidden" name="schedule_id" value="{$shift.schedule_id}">
</form>

<!-- Confirmation Dialog -->
<div id="confirmationDialog" style="display:none;">
    <p>Are you sure you want to Confirm this shift?</p>
    <button onclick="submitForm('confirm_shift')">OK</button>
    <button onclick="submitForm('')">Cancel</button>
</div>

<script>
  function showConfirmation() {
    document.getElementById('confirmationDialog').style.display = 'block';}

  function submitForm(action) {
    var form = document.getElementById('confirmationForm');
    if (action === 'confirm_shift') {
      form.action = '/schedule/?action=confirm_shift';
    } else {
      form.action = '/schedule/?action='; // or any other logic for cancel
    }
    form.submit();
  }
</script>
```

Although it isn't a native Flutter solution, it's easy to style your confirmation/alert dialog however you please, and webview_flutter has no problem handling this type of Javascript on the page.

I hope one of these solutions works for you!